# csv file ouput that with a single row space

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I write a list of tuples to a csv file. Specifically the input would look something like this:

```
newList = [
    ('02-02-2018','18:06:06'),
    ('01-04-2018','15:08:03'),
    ('23-05-2018','07:10:15'),
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
with open('newCSV.csv','w') as newFile:
    writer = csv.writer(newFile)
    writer.writerow(['date','time'])
    writer.writerows(newList)
newFile.close()
```

The output file like this :

```
    date        time
 1  02-02-2018  18:06:06
 2
 3  01-04-2018  15:08:03
 4
 5  23-05-2018  07:10:15
```

why the output file have blank rows between the rows? can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide your code that writes the output.

Comment: @BornTbeWasted I've updated the question

Comment: My output file is perfectly fine, how do you open it to display that output ?

Comment: What is your Python's version?
(And your `newFile.close()` is useless as you're using a context manager)

Comment: @mistiru I use python3.6. I open the output using ms.excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while opening the file specify what need to be printed for the new line

```
with open('newCSV.csv','w', newline='') as newFile:
```